# PDO execute won't inject array values properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wrote a function that selects all the users from my database and all cooresponding fields using PDO. I also allowed the function to take an array as a parameter to allow for easy filtering. My problem is when I pass the filter array to the execute function I don't get any rows from my tables. I know it has something to do with PDO and the way I'm passing my array into it because when I run the execute method with the filter hard coded into the query it works. Here is my function and the code that is calling it:

```
$config = array(
    'filters' => array(
        'all members'     => array('',  ''),
        'officers'            => array('statuses.position_id', '8'),
        'current members'     => array('users.alumni', 0)
    )
);

$filter = $config['filters'];
//Requested filter is just a constant used to keep track of the parsed $_GET value
$result = $dbh->getUsers($filter[REQUESTED_FILTER]);

//Just showed function, not whole class
public function getUsers(array $filter = array('', '')) {
  $result = array();

  $sql = 'SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.grad_year, users.alumni, users.signedISA, phone_numbers.phone_number, emails.email_address,
                addresses.name, addresses.street, addresses.city, addresses.state, addresses.zip
           FROM 
              ((users LEFT JOIN phone_numbers 
                 ON users.user_id = phone_numbers.user_id) 
                 LEFT JOIN emails 
                 ON users.user_id = emails.user_id)
                 LEFT JOIN addresses
                 ON users.user_id = addresses.user_id
                 WHERE ? = ?;';

  $sth = $this->handle->prepare($sql);

  if($sth->execute($filter)) {
     while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($result, $row);
     }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass schema object identifiers (like table or column names) as parameters to a prepared statement (your current attempt is always comparing parameterised string literals from within the `WHERE` clause).

Instead, you will need to do something like:

```
public function getUsers(array $filter = array('\'\'', '')) {
  $result = array();

  $sql = 'SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.grad_year, users.alumni, users.signedISA, phone_numbers.phone_number, emails.email_address,
                addresses.name, addresses.street, addresses.city, addresses.state, addresses.zip
           FROM 
              ((users LEFT JOIN phone_numbers 
                 ON users.user_id = phone_numbers.user_id) 
                 LEFT JOIN emails 
                 ON users.user_id = emails.user_id)
                 LEFT JOIN addresses
                 ON users.user_id = addresses.user_id
                 WHERE ' . $filter[0] . ' = ?;';

  $sth = $this->handle->prepare($sql);

  if($sth->execute($filter[1])) {
     while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($result, $row);
     }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Beware of SQL injection if the value of `$filter` is outside of your control (you'll need to quote identifiers with backticks and double-up any backticks contained therein: make sure you do this in a multi-byte safe way!).

Comment: I had a feeling it had something to do with that. $filter is somewhat out of my control, the user can change the query string to change the filter value. I'll be sure to verify the value coming in from the query string very carefully before running this code. Thank you for your help, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @KylePlusPlus I recommend a **whitelist** to ensure identifiers are valid. If the filter can be a "pseudo query" then parse it first (for whatever definition is required) and *rebuild* it as SQL, **whitelist** the identifiers, and *bind* the values. This ensures that SQL injection is not possible.

Comment: @KylePlusPlus Also, another technique to *mitigate* security vulnerabilities - and can be good to do in any case, even in conduction with a destruct/rebuild scrub - is to connect as "read only" to execute queries that may contain user-generated input.

Comment: @pst Actually, that's pretty much what I'm doing with my query values. I have an array of predetermined filters that just map to the value in the query string. That way, if the query string contains a bogus value, it simply selects everything instead. The main problem with this is I want users to be able to make custom filters, in which case I'll have to do more work with the values.